# Kindle iOS app - how to bulk delete personal documents

Tags: ios, kindle

Is there a way to bulk delete "personal documents" from the Kindle iOS app?

They don't appear under the app folder in itunes when the phone is plugged in to a computer and my web searches have been fruitless.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon help desk confirmed that it is NOT possible to bulk delete personal documents from the iOS app.

(FWIW: I hadn't used the help function in the app before.  They responded very quickly.)